# Placing objects side by side android

Tags: android

I have two buttons on a linear layout that I want to place side by side (right/left of each other), but I can't get them in the right place.

For clarification: I want the fill boxes to be on top of each other, but the buttons at the bottom to be side by side.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="49dp"
    android:hint="@string/FN"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="49dp"
    android:hint="@string/LN"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="49dp"
    android:hint="@string/PN"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="49dp"
    android:hint="@string/EA"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="49dp"
    android:hint="@string/REEA"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="49dp"
    android:hint="@string/User"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="49dp"
    android:hint="@string/Pw"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="49dp"
    android:text="@string/Gender"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="49dp"
    android:text="@string/Country"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/clear" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/submit" />
```

I edited the code so I can be better understood.

The only thing I could find on fixing the problem was setting the layout_weight to be the same, but they just pancake on top of each other.

Thanks.

Comment: use a linear layout for the buttons and another linear layout or relative layout for everything else as per my example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check if this is what you want. 2 buutons on the top of the layout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<Button
android:id="@+id/button1"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:text="clear"
 android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"  />

<Button
android:id="@+id/button2"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="submit"
 android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"  />

</LinearLayout>


<EditText
android:id="@+id/textView1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:hint="FN"
android:inputType="textPersonName"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<EditText
android:id="@+id/textView2"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:hint="LN"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<EditText
android:id="@+id/textView3"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:hint="PN"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<EditText
android:id="@+id/textView4"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:hint="EA"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<EditText
android:id="@+id/textView5"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:hint="REEA"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<EditText
android:id="@+id/textView6"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:hint="user"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView8"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Gender"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView9"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="country"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />



</LinearLayout>
```

if you want your 2 buttons in the bootom then place the linear layout with 2 buttons after yout textView9.Good       Luck!!!

Answer (score 1):

1) set the linear layout holding the buttons to horizontal orientation.

2) set layout weight to 1 for each button

*3) set the width of each button to 0dp

The buttons will now scale and take up 50% each

Edit as per comment:
is this what you want?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
   />

<EditText
     >    
</EditText>

<EditText
   />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"       
    >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
            android:text="Button1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
            android:text="Button2" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Looks like this: 
(edit the layout width in the linear layout to make it not take up the whole screen)

[image]

Comment: I'm making a form, and these 2 buttons go at the bottom, so I want to keep it in vertical. I changed the weight to 1 and the width to 0dp, but now they've just disappeared completely.

Answer (score 0):

assign layout_weight to 1 for both the buttons and android:weightSum=2 to the linearlayout. also, in linearlayout, set the android:orientation="horizontal".

Comment: I want the form to be vertical, I just have two buttons at the bottom that I want to be horizontal.

Comment: OK. Make the LinearLayout orientation to be Vertical. If you make so, the buttons will take the full width and will appear one after other.

Answer (score 0):

For vertical, you can write as:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/clear" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/submit" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

and for horizontal:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/clear" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/submit" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Do it in whatever way you feel like.

Comment: Please take a look back at my example. I need things to be both on top of each other and next to each other.

Comment: can you please add an image of whatever u wanna implement so that i can understand your problem better and give you a proper working solution.

Answer (score 0):

- Add a LinearLayout where you want the buttons to be placed with
  orientation horizontal.
- Place the Buttons inside that LinearLayout.
- Give `layout_weight="1"` to both buttons and `layout_width="0dp"`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
...>

<EditText
.../>

<EditText
.../>

<EditText
.../>

<EditText
... />

<EditText
.../>

<EditText
.../>


<EditText
.../>


<TextView
.../>

<TextView
.../>

<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
...>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/clear" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/submit" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Note**: When you are specifying a long list of view inside a LinearLayout, do check it on all screens especially smaller ones that they all displays correctly. Else use a ScrollView as parent